# 'cp/rsync/scp' by excluding a sub-folder into remote/local machine

Tags: find, scp, cp

I have 50 folders, inside each folder there is **lib** directory which I want to exclude while scp/cp into remote/local machine folder. I did not find any solution using scp but galore using rsync (Which is not installed in loca m/c).

Answer (score 0):

I would select the files you want with `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -path '*/lib/*'
```

Then you can tar those files and copy the tar file:

```
file . -type f ! -path '*/lib/*' -print0 \
| xargs -0 tar zcf - \
| ssh remote_host sh -c 'cd /destination/dir && tar zxvf -'
```